# Is this a safe way to roll a C array or is it prone to segmentation fault?

Tags: c, optimization, segmentation-fault

My application requires many rolling operations over 1d C arrays, and the shift can be any positive or negative integer, so that it can roll back or forth by shift elements. 
Because I need many such operations I am trying to do it as optimal as possible.

I wrote this function for 1-element forward shift:

```
double * myC_roll1dfront( double *ptr, int size){

        double * ptr2 = ptr - 1; //this is a critical point in this question

        *ptr2 = *(ptr+size-1);

        return ptr2;
}
```

and this function for 1-element backward shift.

```
double * myC_roll1dback( double *ptr, int size){

        double * ptr2 = ptr + 1;  //this is a critical point in this question

        *(ptr+size) = *ptr;

        return ptr2;
}
```

Then in case shift is bigger than -+1 I call the above shift times from this one:

```
double * myC_roll1d( double *ptr, int size, int shift){

        double * ptr2;
        double * temp = ptr;

        if (shift > 0){
                for(int i=0; i<shift; i++){
                        ptr2 = myC_roll1dfront(temp, size);
                        temp = ptr2;
                }
        }

        if (shift < 0){
                for(int i=0; i<abs(shift); i++){
                        ptr2 = myC_roll1dback(temp, size);
                        temp = ptr2;
                }
        }

        if (shift == 0) ptr2 = ptr;

        return ptr2;
}
```

The code works totally perfect and I think is an optimal implementation since it takes only
shift read/write operations. For example when I need to shift by 1 element I don't copy all data 1 position back and add the first to the end. What I do is to shift the pointer one step back and write the last element in this position which now becomes the first position.

My concern is that I access a memory location that I shouldn't (`double * ptr2 = ptr - 1` or here `*(ptr+size) = *ptr;`), but I didn't got any segmentation fault.

Is my concern correct, or shouldn't I worry at all?

Comment: Whether the "shift" is valid or not depends on how `ptr` (arg in `myC_roll1d`) was allocated and what it points to. You haven't shown that.

Comment: Yes that's true @usr , thanks for your note. The pointer is allocated dynamically with malloc as:  `double *array = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);` and I always pass it with reference to the first position, like this: `array = myC_roll1d(array, size, shift);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you use the functions. For instance, this would obviously be a problem:

```
int arr[10] = {0};
int *p = myC_roll1dfront(arr, 10);
```

Because `ptr2` would then point to `arr[-1]`. But calling it like this:

```
int arr[10] = {0};
int *p = myC_roll1dfront(&arr[1], 9);
```

is perfectly valid.

Comment: So it is up to the usage, but in general it isn't a safe implementation. Thank you!